# How to spin an angled div?

Tags: html, css, animation, rotation

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
   document.getElementById("dieo").classList.add("roll");
});
```

```css
#die{
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    /*background-color:  yellowgreen;*/
    float: left;
}

#dieo{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    color: #000;
    margin-left: auto ! important;
    margin-right: auto ! important;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-top: 27px;
}
#d61{
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#d62{
    margin-left: -14px;
    margin-top: 41px;
}
#d63{
    margin-left: 23px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#d64{
   margin-left: 22px;
    margin-top: 22px;
}
#d65{
   margin-left: 24px;
   margin-top: -50px;
}
#d66{
   margin-left: 24px;
   margin-top: -14px;
}
.dot{
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.roll{
    animation: roll 0.3s linear 10;
}
@keyframes roll{
    0%{
        transform: rotateX(45deg);
      transform: rotateY(30deg);
    }
    25%{
         transform: rotateX(45deg);
      transform: rotateY(60deg);
 }
    50%{
         transform: rotateX(45deg);
      transform: rotateY(90deg);
    }
    75%{
         transform: rotateX(45deg);
       transform: rotateY(60deg);
    }
    100%{
         transform: rotateX(45deg);
        transform: rotateY(30deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="die">
   <div id="dieo">
       <div id="d6">
           <div id="d61" class="dot"></div>
           <div id="d62" class="dot"></div>
           <div id="d63" class="dot"></div>
           <div id="d64" class="dot"></div>
           <div id="d65" class="dot"></div>
           <div id="d66" class="dot"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="btn"> ROLL </button>
```

In the above code ,I'm trying to spin the div "die".But when I click on the button the div losses it's angle.**Is it possible to spin the die without lost it's angle?**
I'm also tried `rotate3d()` but which also not works for me.any help will get appreciated...!!!

Comment: Why do not you turn the whole container in which the animation is going on?
`#die{
    transform: rotate(45deg); 
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small correction. Change in your JS ID dieo to die. [LiveFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/c18qyw86/1/)
I add my own jQuery on fiddle.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
   document.getElementById("die").classList.add("roll");
});
```

```css
#die{
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    /*background-color:  yellowgreen;*/
    float: left;
}

#dieo{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    color: #000;
    margin-left: auto ! important;
    margin-right: auto ! important;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-top: 27px;
}
#d61{
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#d62{
    margin-left: -14px;
    margin-top: 41px;
}
#d63{
    margin-left: 23px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#d64{
   margin-left: 22px;
    margin-top: 22px;
}
#d65{
   margin-left: 24px;
   margin-top: -50px;
}
#d66{
   margin-left: 24px;
   margin-top: -14px;
}
.dot{
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.roll{
    animation: roll 0.3s linear 10;
}
@keyframes roll{
    0%{
        transform: rotateX(45deg);
      transform: rotateY(30deg);
    }
    25%{
         transform: rotateX(45deg);
      transform: rotateY(60deg);
 }
    50%{
         transform: rotateX(45deg);
      transform: rotateY(90deg);
    }
    75%{
         transform: rotateX(45deg);
       transform: rotateY(60deg);
    }
    100%{
         transform: rotateX(45deg);
        transform: rotateY(30deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script></script>
<div id="die">
   <div id="dieo">
       <div id="d6">
           <div id="d61" class="dot"></div>
           <div id="d62" class="dot"></div>
           <div id="d63" class="dot"></div>
           <div id="d64" class="dot"></div>
           <div id="d65" class="dot"></div>
           <div id="d66" class="dot"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="btn"> ROLL </button>
```

Comment: sorry ,to tick your answer after a long time

Comment: don't feel sorry  :)